# Controlar proyector desde C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

Estoy empezando con *C#*, anteriormente ya había hecho un programa con *Visual Basic*, el cual se proyectaba mediante un video **beam**. Ahora quiero migrar este programa a *C#* y quería saber si este lenguaje dispone de alguna herramienta o función para desactivar la proyección del vídeo *beam* sin apagarlo, como cuando sucede con una presentación que llega a su fin en *Power Point*, el video *beam* deja de proyectar pero no se apaga.

Comment: Si usas net framework en c# tienes acceso a las mismas librerias que visual basic

Comment: Eso me sirve, pero visual basic puede desactivar la proyección de un video beam y por cual función podría hacerlo?

Comment: Puedes intentar con esto https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&sp=nmt4&tl=es&u=https://www.codeproject.com/kb/cs/monitor_management_guide.aspx&usg=ALkJrhhd6rFSDnsTU53cJKq0u_0aye8MYA